# Rails 3 : Mass update

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to use mass-update every operation in a single view, with a single update button. Using this following code, Rails thows this error

```
Showing /home/vincent/git/gestion/app/views/operations/tag.html.erb where line #23 raised:

undefined method `merge' for 1:Fixnum
Extracted source (around line #23):

20:         <td>
21:             <% @tags.each do |elem| %>
22:             <%= f.label elem.tag %>
23:             <%= f.check_box "operation[tag_ids][]", elem.id, operation.tags.include?(elem) %>
24:             <% end %>
25:         </td>
26:         <td><%= f.submit %></td>
```

Models

```
class Operation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :credit, :date_operation, :debit, :libelle, :tag_ids
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags, :allow_destroy=>true
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :tag
  has_and_belongs_to_many :operations
end
```

Controller

```
  def tag
    @operations = Operation.limit(100)
    @tags = Tag.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { "tag" }# tag.html.erb
#      format.json { render json: @operations }
    end
  end
```

View

```
<% @operations.each do |operation| %>
    <tr>

        <td><%= operation.date_operation %></td>
        <td><%= operation.libelle %></td>
        <td><%= operation.credit %></td>
        <td><%= operation.debit %></td>
        <%= form_for operation do |f| %>
        <td>
            <% @tags.each do |elem| %>
            <%= f.label elem.tag %>
            <%= f.check_box "operation[tag_ids][]", elem.id, operation.tags.include?(elem) %>
            <% end %>
        </td>
        <td><%= f.submit %></td>
        <% end %>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
```

Do you have any clue/help about this problem?

Thank you in advance

Edit 1 : adding full stack trace

Comment: Might help if you include the full stack trace from the error; it would show the lines triggering the error.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I've added the stack trace to help you help me.

Comment: Change the `f.check_box` for `check_box_tag`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `f.check_box` for `check_box_tag`, for instance:

```
<%= check_box_tag "operation[tag_ids][]", elem.id, operation.tags.include?(elem) %>
```

The problem in this scenario is that `f.check_box` is expecting that the value is bounded to the form which in not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

use nested_form gem for this case i think it will work.

for more about nested_form  Click [here](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form)